# How to use `-s` option of `diff` command

Tags: zsh, macos, diff

I am using the command(diff) on macOS. The document says:

```
-s --report-identical-files
             Causes diff to report files which are the same, which are
             otherwise not mentioned.
```

However, the command always says "files are identical" with `-s` option.

```
% echo "aaa" > a.txt
% echo "bbb" > b.txt
% diff -s a.txt b.txt 
1c1
< aaa
---
> bbb
Files a.txt and b.txt are identical
```

Isn't it weird..?

Comment: I don't get your result using `diff (GNU diffutils) 3.10`, but can using the default `Apple diff (based on FreeBSD diff)`, so probably a bug.

Comment: indeed I have both `diff`s on my mac and got the issue with `/usr/bin/diff` which is `Apple diff (based on FreeBSD diff)`

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in the implementation of `diff` on macOS Sonoma not present in macOS Big Sur. The issue must have appeared in one of the intermediate Monterey or Ventura releases.

[Someone says](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/diff-s-bug-not-too-serious.2412365/) they noticed the issue in an earlier release of Sonoma and that they reported the issue to Apple, but they (and I) can confirm that the bug still exists in macOS Sonoma 14.2.